# jquery event from a dynamically loaded element to its parent

Tags: jquery

I add dynamically the below HTML with the `.load()` function:

```
<div class="todelete"><a href="#" class="delete"></a></div>
```

Then I wish to do something like this:

```
$("a.delete").live('click', function() {
    $("a.delete").parent("div").remove();
});
```

but nothing; it seems that it doesn't know who "this" is referring to.

How can I fix this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`parent("div")` will return you an array of all the `div` elements higher in the DOM tree from the current element. Try `closest()` instead, which will just return the single clsest div.

Also, use `$(this)` in your handler to only target the element which is being clicked on, rather than all `.delete` elements.

```
$("a.delete").live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

Comment: Yeah! this works perfectly, it's all I need! Thank you so much! If you want you can vote my question. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference it like this:

```
$("a.delete").live('click', function() { 
$(this).closest("div").remove(); 
})
```

For example, see:
http://jsbin.com/urugow/edit#preview

UPDATE: Made a better example in jsbin

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the example! You are very kind. If you want you can vote my question. Bye!

Answer (score 0):

If you move your live() function to be nested inside the function that creates the div.todelete it should work.

From my experience you cannot access a dynamicly created div, unless you create the function at the time the div is created.

Comment: thank you for your answer; it is already nested in the same function, but nothing...